# How to determine highest power of $2$ in $3^{1024}-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Highest power of two that divided $3^{1024}-1$

> *Q: I did from binomial and expansion but is there a smarter way ?*

My approach :
$ 3^{1024}-1 $ can be $(3^{512} + 1)$ and $(3^{512} – 1)$
$\quad $Again $( 3^{512} – 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{256} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{256} – 1)$
$\quad \quad $Again $( 3^{256} – 1 ) $ is written as $( 3^{128} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{128} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3 ^{128} – 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{64} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{64} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{64} – 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{32} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{32} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{32} – 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{16}+ 1 )$ and $( 3^{16} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{16}– 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{8}+ 1 )$ and $( 3^{8} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{8} – 1 )$ is written as $( 3^{4} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{4}– 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{4}– 1)$ is written as $(3^{2} + 1)$ and $( 3^{2} – 1)$

---

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $Again $( 3^{2} – 1)$ is written as $( 3^{1} + 1 )$ and $( 3^{1} – 1)$
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $or $ 2^2 $and$ 2^1$

Now it can be observed that each of $( 3^{512} + 1), ( 3^{256} + 1) , ( 3^{128} + 1) , ( 3^{64} + 1)$ , $( 3^{32} + 1)$ , $(3^{16} + 1) , (3^{8} + 1)$ , $(3^{4} + 1) , ( 3^{2} + 1)$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $ 2^{2}$.

In other words, maximum power of $2$ that can divided each of $( 3^{512}+ 1), ( 3^{256}+ 1) $ , $ ( 3^{128} + 1) , ( 3^{64}+ 1)$ , $( 3^{32} + 1) , (3^{16} + 1) , (3^{8} + 1) $,$ (3^{4} + 1)$ and $( 3^{2} + 1)$ is $1$.

As they are total $9$ terms hence expression is divisible by $2^9$ and rest two terms $2^2$ and $2^1$ will be divisible by $2^3$. Hence, maximum power of $2$ that can divide $3^{1024} – 1$ is $12$.

Comment: And where did you use the binomial ?

Comment: $3^{2^n } \equiv 1  \ \ \ (2^{n+1})$

Comment: This was another approach binomial was other

Comment: But from this explanation n = 11

Comment: This explanation says that $2^{11}$ divides the expression. It does not prove that it is the highest such power.

Comment: As theorems like little Fermat (cf. PantelisDamianou) give only lower bounds, I thnk your ways to find the exact exponent is very ok. You might of course have made this an induction proof of $2^{n+2}||3^{2^n}-1$ for $n\ge1$.

Comment: @ArpitBajpai how you use binomial can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the notation $\{m,p\}$ for the highest power of a prime p dividing *m* and the "iverson-bracket" *($[n:p]=1$ if p divides n and $[n:p]=0$ if not)* we can write:
$$\{3^n-1,2\}=1+ [n:2] + \{n,2\} \tag1 $$
for *n=1024* this is
$$ \{3^{1024}-1,2\} = 2 + \{1024,2\} = 2+ 10 = 12 $$
The aspect of being "a smarter method" lays in a small framework for the description of the more general problem of composition by primefactors of expressions $f_{b,a}(n)=b^n-a^n$ (for some fixed *a* and *b* but dependend on varying *n*) using the Fermat's/Euler's observations of cyclicityness of the residues modulo some prime *p*. Then (1) has a form which is pretty general for any base *b*, *a=1* and primefactors *p*. I've a small [treatize](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf) on this method in case this is interesting (which I personally find "smarter", so this appears here in an answer to your question).

*[added, a neat example,[treatize (updated, includes now powertower-iteration)](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf)]:* For instance, that scheme allows iteration; assume that *n* itself is of the form $n = 3^m - 1$ then 
$$ \begin{eqnarray} \{3^{3^m-1}-1,2\} &=& \{3^n-1,2\} \\ &=& 1 + [n:2] + \{n,2\} \\
 &=& 1+1+(\{3^m-1,2\}) \\ &=&  1+1+(1+ [m:2] + \{m,2\}) \\ &=& 3+ [m:2] + \{m,2\} 
 \end{eqnarray} $$
and in general, for a *powertower* of height *h* with topmost coefficient *n*
$$ = 2 h - 1 + [n:2] + \{n,2\} $$
which I find an amazing example of reduction of big numbers ...

Comment: Interesting method!

Answer (score 7):

Let $2^a||(3^{2^b}-1)\implies 3^{2^b}=1+c2^a$ where $c$ is odd.

$3^{2^{b+1}}=(3^{2^b})^2=(1+c2^a)^2=1+c2^{a+1}+c^22^{2a}=1+c2^{a+1}(1+c2^{a-1})$ if $a>1$

$\implies 2^{a+1}||(3^{2^{b+1}}-1)$

Now, $3^2=1+2^3$ here $a=3,b=1$, i.e, $2^3||(3^{2^1}-1)\implies 2^{k+2}||(3^{2^k}-1)$

Here in this problem, $k=10$

Comment: Elegant solution! +1

Comment: What does || means ? I think i know just that | means divides

Comment: @Orion_Pax,  $$||$$  highest power of $2$. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I see thanks ..