# Notation for "the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, prime-numbers, divisibility

If $p$ is a prime and $n$ an integer, is there a standard or commonly used notation for "the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$"?

It's a concept that is often used repeatedly in number-theoretic proofs (see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int/2747#2747)), and a convenient notation could make such proofs much more concise.  [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207071/highest-power-of-2/207105#207105) uses the notation $\{n,p\}$, which is convenient but seems not to be widely used.

Edit: Prompted by Thomas Kildetoft's comment below, by a convenient notation I mean one which facilitates not only simple statements such as:

- $m$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$.

but also more complex statements such as:

- $m$ = (The highest power of $p$ that divides $n$) + 1

Comment: The Lifting The Exponent Lemma paper uses the notation $\upsilon_p(n)$.

Comment: Wikipedia gives $\nu_p(n)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a standard notation, namely $p^e\mid\mid n$, which says that $e$ is the largest power of $p$ which divides $n$.

Reference: Martin Aigner, Number Theory.

Edit: For more advanced purposes, like $p$-adic numbers etc., a common notation is also $\nu_p(n)$, which also then appears in more elementary context. For elementary number theory I have seen $p^e\mid\mid n$ more often, though.

Comment: I think a main difference between the notations is that $\nu_p$ is a function that returns the $e$ above, while $p^e\mid\mid n$ is a statement (so the second is more convenient if one needs to include it in formulas).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think you mean the first, not the second. Generally functions are more convenient than relations.

Comment: @BillDubuque I meant in the order they were mentioned in the answer, but I realize that was not very clear.

Comment: Does $p$ have to be prime to be able to use $\nu_p$? And how is it read?

Answer (score 6):

This can be seen as a special case of the more general concept of valuations (on discrete valuation rings).

A common notation in that context, which is quite convenient also here is $\nu_p(n)$.